# How to concatenate string within class name syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a huge string like this:

```
'<i class=""></i>'
```

I have a variable called `icon`. I need to place `icon` in between the two quotes. Although it feels simple, I've been struggling to wrap my head around it. Can someone please help? JS newbie here.

Comment: In `class`'s quotes or between `<i>` tags?

Comment: Sorry, inside the class, its a font-awesome icon. It'll be something like "fa fa-building"

Comment: Answer below will do the job,

Comment: `<i class=""></i>'.replace('""', '"' + icon + '"')` might do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delimiters of your string are `'`, so just end the `'`, concatenate the `icon`, and resume the `'`:

```js
const icon = 'myIcon';
const str = '<i class="' + icon + '"></i>';
console.log(str);
```

But you might find it more readable to use a template literal instead, especially if you're building an HTML string, or if it's multi-line, or if you're having any issues with escape characters: begin and end the string with backticks, and insert variables by putting them inside of `${varNameHere}`:

```js
const icon = 'myIcon';
const icon2 = 'myIcon2';
const icon3 = 'myIcon3';
const str = `
<i class="${icon}"></i>
<i class="${icon2}"></i>
<i class="${icon3}"></i>
`;
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Oh neat, this worked! I did NOT know about template literals! That can solve so many of my previous problems! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can split it using .split() function.

```
  const icon = 'Idk'
  var str = '<i class = "">';
  var strSplit = str.split('"');
  var addString = strSplit[0] + '"' + icon + '"' + strSplit[2];
  console.log(addString);
```

The array strSplit contains `['<i class = ','','>']`