# Concatenate javascript string and variable in an echo statement

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to limit the size of a paragraph of text. The wrapper div has a dynamically created ID and the paragraph text is also dynamically inserted. The HTML and JavaScript are in the same file.

The HTML

```
echo"
...
   <div id ='subTextWrapper$sub_id' >
      <p>$submission_text</p>
   </div>
...";
```

The JavaScript:

```
echo"
<script>
...
var submissionId = $sub_id;

//Limit size of a submission if too long and show a link to read more
var submissionString = $('#subTextWrapper' + submissionId).html();

if (submissionString.split(' ').length > 50) {
   $('#subTextWrapper' + submissionId).html(submissionString.split(' ').slice(0, 50).join(' ') 
   + ' ... '
   + `<a class='read-more' + submissionId>Read more</a>`);
}

$('a.read-more' + submissionId).click(function () {
    $('#subTextWrapper' + submissionId).html(submissionString);
});
...
</script>";
```

In the if statement above I want to concatenate the class name `read-more` with ``` the variable submissionId:

```
`<a class='read-more' + submissionId>Read more</a>`
```

This doesn't seem to work. I am not an expert in JS, so any help would be appreciated. Just a note, when I remove the variable `submissionId` then it works, but obviously it expands all my dynamically created submissions.

Comment: You concatenation seems wrong: `"<a class='read-more" + submissionId + "'>Read more</a>"` or `"<a class='read-more@Sub.'>Read more</a>".replace('@Sub.', submissionId)`

Comment: That `echo`, is that PHP?

Comment: What is the server-side language - PHP? Please add a tag for it, because you aren't working with pure JS here but you're trying to generate JS/HTML code from the server-side. This would involve reconciliating the server-side syntax with the client-side code required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258094/how-to-concatenate-string-within-class-name-syntax-in-javascript) seems wrong.

What you are currently inserting is exactly what you see as string:

```
<a class='read-more' + submissionId>Read more</a>
```

and not the value of `submissionId`. Since you are not handling the two different delimiters correctly. You have ` enclosing the whole `a` element and ' enclosing the class. You are closing the class before adding the `submissionId` and not closing the main literal to acutally include the value of `submissionId` 
.

You can fix it like (if `submissionId` is a string):

```
`<a class='read-more` + submissionId.trim() + `'>Read more</a>`
```

or

```
`<a class='read-more@Sub.'>Read more</a>`.replace('@Sub.', submissionId.trim())
```

You could also use an array to build your string to avoid the different delimiters:

```
//var submissionId = 1234;
var tString = [];
tString.push("<a class='read-more"); //REM: Open the class attribute and not closing it since submissionId  is part of the class
tString.push(submissionId); //REM: Adding the value of submissionId
tString.push("'>Read more</a>"); //REM: Closing the class attribute
console.log(tString.join('')); //-> <a class='read-more1234'>Read more</a>
```

Since `submissionId` looks like an id/number to me, please be aware that [classnames shall not start with digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors).

Furthermore if you want to limit the characters of a string you could use [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead:

```
submissionString.substring(0, 50);
```

Comment: The first solution seems to work (without the trim function). I have to wrap my head around why the mix of single quotes and template literals work like that in this particular case. But I'll have a bit of a read. Thanks.

Comment: @Pieter Steyn: So that means `submissionId` is a numeric value? Then a `trim()` wont be available indeed. The quotes do not work because you are not ending the initial one. You have the ` one enclosing the whole tag and the ' enclosing the class attribute and you are not ending/starting those correctly.

Comment: Yes ```submissionId``` is a numeric variable. Wrt the quotes, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

would it not work like so.

```
echo"
<script>
//Limit size of a submission if too long and show a link to read more
var submissionString = $('#subTextWrapper' + submissionId).html();
if (submissionString.split(' ').length > 50) {
$('#subTextWrapper' + submissionId).html(submissionString.split(' ').slice(0, 
50).join(' ') 
+ ' ... '
+ `<a class='read-more' + submissionId>Read more</a>`);
}
$('a.read-more'$sub_id).click(function () {
$('#subTextWrapper'$sub_id).html(submissionString);
});
...
</script>";
```

or you could also concatenate like so

```
 $('a.read-more'".$sub_id.")
```